# Swift 3 AVCaptureSession image output is in portrait instead of landscape

Tags: swift3, avfoundation, orientation, avcapturesession, ios-camera

I made a simple iOS app that takes photos and saves it to the device's library. I'm expecting a landscape image as output but what is produced by the camera is a portrait orientation of a landscape image, say a 50x100, the image is rotated to 90 degrees. I wanted the image to be in landscape and I'm not sure what's wrong with my code.

I needed my preview layer to be in landscape so I set my AVCaptureVideoOrientation to the desired orientation.

```
previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.landscapeRight
```

Here is the configuration:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
    for device in devices! {
        if (device as AnyObject).position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.back {

            do {

                let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device as! AVCaptureDevice)

                if (captureSession.canAddInput(input)) {

                    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
                    captureSession.addInput(input)
                    sessionOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG]


                    if (captureSession.canAddOutput(sessionOutput)) {

                        captureSession.addOutput(sessionOutput)
                        captureSession.startRunning()

                        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResize
                        previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.landscapeRight
                        previewLayer.frame = self.cameraView.bounds
                        cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

                        previewLayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.cameraView.frame.width / 2, y: self.cameraView.frame.height / 2)
                        previewLayer.bounds = cameraView.frame

                        cameraView.addSubview(captureBtn)
                        cameraView.addSubview(shutterTimer)

                    }

                }

            } catch let err {

                print(err)
                return

            }

        }
    }

}
```

Image output

```
if let videoConnection = sessionOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) {

        sessionOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: { (buffer, error) in

            let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(buffer)
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)!
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
            print(UIImage(data: imageData!)!)

        })

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I got it!, So before you save your images to the library, you have to set the output's orientation based on what's on your preview layer by simply adding this line:

```
videoConnection.videoOrientation = .landscapeRight
```

....

```
if let videoConnection = sessionOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) {
        // set output orientation before saving
        videoConnection.videoOrientation = .landscapeRight
        sessionOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: { (buffer, error) in

            let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(buffer)
            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)!
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)                
        })

    }
```